# PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

In my application, I have a dialog box that displays 2 options : `Copy` and `Dismiss`
I want a notification in the Status bar when the user clicks `Copy`.

```
public void showDialog(final String planet) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Here You Go!");
    dialogBuilder.setMessage(planet);
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Copy", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                clipboard.setText(planet);
            } else {
                android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
                android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("",planet);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(List.this, List.class);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        }
```

With this is code I get an error on `PendingIntent.getActivity` informing that `The method getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}, int, Intent, int)`.
 The quick fix doesn't help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `WhateverYourActivityIsThatIsCallingYourShowDialogMethod.this` instead of `this`, where `WhateverYourActivityIsThatIsCallingYourShowDialogMethod` is the name of the activity in which this `showDialog()` method resides.